# Why is my for loop not iterating in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to run an alphabetical sequence in Linux shell.  I believe my syntax is correct, but its not giving me each letter, but rather `{a..z}` all at once.  Here is what I have:

```
COUNTER=0;   
for X in {a..z};
do
    # Make sure usb is mounted before trying anything
    sudo mkdir /media/mounts/sd${X}1
    sudo mount /dev/sd${X}1 /media/mounts/sd${X}1

    # Find player number from Linux mount point
    DATA_DIR=/media/mounts/sd${X}1;
    PLAYER_FILE_PATH=`find $DATA_DIR -name "player.*"`;
    PLAYER_FILE_ONLY=`basename -- $PLAYER_FILE_PATH`;
    PLAYER_NUMBER=`echo "${PLAYER_FILE_ONLY##*.}"`;
    
    # Make sure usb device exists and player number is not empty
    if [ -n "$PLAYER_NUMBER" ] && [ $PLAYER_NUMBER -gt 0 ]
    then
        # Let user know which tracer was found
        echo "$PLAYER_NUMBER was found, creating directory to store its .dat files" | tee -a $ERR_LOG_PATH;
        echo "${PLAYER_NUMBER}: " >> $LOG_PATH;
        let COUNTER++;

        # Create directory for player number to dump .dat files and log any errors at output
        sudo mkdir $DUMP_DIR/$PLAYER_NUMBER;
        NUMBER_DATS=`ls $DATA_DIR/MountsData/*.dat | wc -l`;
        DAT_COUNT_ARRAY[$PLAYER_NUMBER]=$NUMBER_DATS
        echo "USB $PLAYER_NUMBER has $NUMBER_DATS .dat files";
        echo "${NUMBER_DATS}\r\n" >> $LOG_PATH;
        cp $DATA_DIR/MountsData/*.dat $DUMP_DIR/$PLAYER_NUMBER 2>> $ERR_LOG_PATH;
        
        # Remove all .dat files directly from usb and log any errors at output
        sudo rm $DATA_DIR/MountsData/*.dat 2>> $ERR_LOG_PATH;
    fi
done
```

I get the resulting output:

```
mount: special device /dev/sd{a..z}1 does not exist
```

I have tried changing the variable names, capitalization, and referring to them as `$X` instead of `${X}`. I am currently using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with a standard Raspbian shell.  I ran some test to ensure syntax was right in the terminal and seems like the for loop structure is correct.  Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like your shell doesn't support brace expansion.

Comment: You aren't using `bash` or other shell that supports brace expansion, so the loop executes once with `X` bound to the literal string `{a..z}`.

Comment: Interesting... Okay, so is there an easy way I can do a similar method without having to make a ginormous array?

Comment: `{a..z}` creates the equivalent of a ginormous array anyway; it has to expand the expression to the full list of 26 characters before the `for` loop can iterate over it.

Comment: I tried to make an array in my shell before but it doesn't like the `declare` or `=(# # #)` declaration.  Is there another method of doing this?

Comment: you can try `for x in $(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=97;i<=122;i++) printf "%c ",i}'); do echo $x; done`

Comment: Can your question be simplified to `for X in {a..z}; do echo "X=$X"; done` ?

Comment: OMG you are a life saver, thank you!  I never even though of iterating the ASCII characters lol.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Isn't `bash` included in Raspbian?

Comment: Just begin the script with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I have #!/bin/bash in my script.  I am running some custom modules on my Pi, so that might be the issue I am running into.  @karakfa 's answer worked flawlessly

Comment: `perl -e '$,=" "; print (a..z)'`

Comment: If you start the script with `sh yourscript`, that overrides the `#!/bin/bash`. For your shell to have access to bash features (of which `{a..z}` is one), it needs to run with bash as the active interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute it with bash.
some os link sh to bash, but some of them link to other shell apps like the dash in ubuntu.
to check the linked app in your sh, try to execute this command:
**file -h /bin/sh**

Answer (score 0):

You can write a portable function that will generate the list in a POSIX compatible way. For example to generate a range of ASCII characters from any character (with lower ASCII value) to any ASCII character, you can do:

```sh
genasciirange() {
    [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" ] || return 1
    local a=$(LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1")
    local b=$(LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$2")
    [ "$a" -lt "$b" -a "$a" -lt 256 -a "$b" -lt 256 ] || return 1
    local c="$a"
    while [ "$c" -le "$b" ]; do
        printf " \\$(printf '%03o' "$c")"
        c=$((c+1))
    done
    printf "\n"
}
```

(where `-a` is the older AND for conditions within `[...]`, you can replace with `[...] && [...]` if you desire)

The conversion from character to ASCII value is handled by `LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$somechar"` and from ASCII value to character by converting to octal value and then outputting the escaped octal code, e.g. `printf " \\$(printf '%03o' "$someasciival")"`

**Example Use/Output**

```
genasciirange a z
 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

or for example:

```
genasciirange Q q
 Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q
```

In your case, you can include the function and replace the brace-expansion with:

```sh
for X in $(genasciirange a z)
```

**Using the `jot` Utility**

A fairly common utility available is `jot`. It is simply an advanced `seq` that can generate sequential or random data. For example, for `a-z` you could do:

```sh
jot -s " " -w %c 26 a
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

It is likely available for your Linux distribution already. If not, you can build from source [athena-jot-9.0.orig.tar.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/athena-jot/athena-jot_9.0.orig.tar.gz) from [Ubuntu Source Package: athena-jot (9.0-7)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/athena-jot)

`awk` can be used as well.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.